# Is there anyway to use valgrind tool on windows machine?

Tags: windows, valgrind

I have one executable file (generated from C and C++ source files) on my laptop which is having Windows Operating system. I need to check whether the executable file is having any memory leaks or any errors using valgrind. But I have no idea how to use valgrind from windows machine or whether we can use valgrind from windows. Can any one please let me know whether we can use valgrind from Windows? Can you please suggest any other memory debugging tools if we can't use valgrind from windows machine?

Comment: AFAIK, valgrind only runs on Linux.  But you (theoretically anyway) could rebuild your executable for Linux, since C/C++ is cross platform.  I do not know how true this is, but valgrind is supposedly such a valuable tool, some projects support Linux just to be able to run it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual C++ has [CRT Debug Heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx#bkmk_heap_state_reporting_functions) functions such as [_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d41t22sb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).